# Scrape urls if newer than lastmod date -Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, sitemap

Hi I want to only scrape pages whose `lastmod` date is newer than specific date.

For example: Only scrape the url if `lastmod` is 14/9/2017 or newer.

I use this code to scrape all the pages but I can't restrict it based on `lastmod` date:

```
import requests
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
from urllib.parse import urljoin


class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'sitemap_spider'
    robots_url = 'http://www.example.org/robots.txt'

    sitemap_urls = [robots_url]
    sitemap_follow = ['products-eg-ar']

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

This is my `robots.txt`

```
sitemap: /sitemap-products-eg-ar-index-1-local.xml
```

the `sitemap-products-eg-ar-index-1-local.xml` contains:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap>
     <loc>/sitemap-products-eg-ar-1.xml</loc>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
     <loc>/sitemaps/sitemap-products-eg-ar-2.xml</loc>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

and `sitemap-products-eg-ar-2.xml` contains:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
 <url>
  <loc>/product-8112041/i/</loc>
  <priority>0.8</priority>
  <lastmod>2017-06-17</lastmod>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
 </url>
</urset>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with standard `SitemapSpider` class. You would have to subclass it and modify its `_parse_sitemap` method where it deals with `urlset`. As this method internally uses `iterloc` function from `sitemap` module, a more dirty solution would be just to redefine that function to take into account `lastmod` element. Something like this:

```
import datetime
import scrapy

oldest = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-09-14', '%Y-%m-%d')

def _iterloc(it, alt=False):
    for d in it:
        lastmod = datetime.datetime.strptime(d['lastmod'], '%Y-%m-%d')
        if lastmod > oldest:
            yield d['loc']

            # Also consider alternate URLs (xhtml:link rel="alternate")
            if alt and 'alternate' in d:
                for l in d['alternate']:
                    yield l

scrapy.spiders.sitemap.iterloc = _iterloc

# your spider code here
```